# How to write this function in latex?

Tags: math-mode

How to write these equations in latex? Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What in particular are you struggling with?

Comment: If you would like to learn quickly how to type math in LaTeX, try [this link](http://webdemo.myscript.com/views/math.html), afterwards, if you have a specific problem, ask us providing a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), we will happy to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try and read an introductory manual, such as [Nicola Talbot's](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/)

For these two formulas, there are just a few points to consider.

1. The centered dot for the scalar product is called `\cdot`
2. The summation symbol is called `\sum`
3. The fancy letter “l” is called `\ell`
4. The boldface “x” is obtained with `\mathbf{x}`
5. The boldface “Phi” needs `\bm{\Phi}` (and `\usepackage{bm}`)
6. For better alignment of the subscripts to the alphas following the top summation symbol, the input should be `\alpha_{i}^{0}y_{i}^{}` (with an empty superscript)

From a mathematical point of view, since the scalar product applies to two vectors, which seem to be denoted with boldface (upright) letters, also `w` should be `\mathbf{w}`.

However, directly using `\mathbf` or `\bm` in the document is discouraged: if the journal's editors tell you that vectors should be boldface *italic*, you'd be in a bad situation.

I'll show a document with some mock text with `kantlipsum`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just for the example

\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} % or \bm{#1}
\newcommand{\vectf}[1]{\bm{#1}} % for vector functions with Greek letters

\begin{document}

\kant*[1]% this stands for some unspecified text
\begin{equation*}
f(\vect{x}) = \vect{w} \cdot \vectf{\Phi}(\vect{x})+b
= \sum_{i}\alpha_{i}^{0}y_{i}^{}K(\vect{x}_{i},\vect{x})+b
\end{equation*}
\kant*[2]% this stands for some unspecified text
\begin{equation*}
W^{2}(\alpha)=\sum_{i=1}^{\ell}\alpha_{i}-
\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j=1}^{\ell}\alpha_{i}\alpha_{j}y_{i}y_{j}K(\vect{x}_{i},\vect{x}_{j})
\end{equation*}
\kant*[3]% this stands for some unspecified text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Try changing `\mathbf` into `\bm` in the definition of `\vect` and you'll see the difference after running LaTeX again. For instance, the first formula would become, with no other intervention,

[image]

Comment: Neither `w` and `\Phi` of the question look bold to me. But, of course, it is interesting, how to make them bold.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Maybe `\Phi` is not bold, but `w` should definitely be, as I explained in the answer, assuming the centered period stands for scalar product. It's a matter of personal preference using boldface for vector valued functions, but with the usage of `\vectf` it's easy to switch to medium weight.

Comment: Then, `b` could also be a vector, e.g. `w` meaning "weights" and `b` meaning "biases". And `x_i` could be a scalar component of `x`. But without knowing the definition ranges and domains of the functions and variables it is hard to tell.